# CDI - using interceptor class from library

Tags: java, logging, glassfish, cdi, interceptor

Can we use annotation-based interceptor in ejb-jar from a different ejb-jar?
I tried it with the @Logged example, but stucked with it. Can somebody help me out?

In core.jar:

```
@Inherited
@InterceptorBinding
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Target({METHOD, TYPE})
public @interface Logged {}
```

and

```
@Logged
@Interceptor
public class LoggedInterceptor implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public LoggedInterceptor() {
    }

    @AroundInvoke
    public Object logMethodEntry(InvocationContext invocationContext)
            throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Entering method: "
            + invocationContext.getMethod().getName() + " in class "
            + invocationContext.getMethod().getDeclaringClass().getName());

        return invocationContext.proceed();
    }
}
```

The question is: how to use this interceptor from another ejb-jar (inside an Enterprise Application)? For example: logging business method calls, where methods can be found in different modules:

module1.jar:

```
public class ModuleClass{
    @Logged public void doSomething(){...}
}
```

I've tried to put <interceptor><class..... to beans.xml too, but its not working for me.

Thanks for any advice!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That should definitely work, even though I recall that I fiddled quite a bit on JBoss 6.

You will have to activate the interceptor in the `beans.xml` of the JAR where it's defined, and I *think* there was an issue with EAR deployments, but that's quite a while ago and I don't have access to the source code any more.

Should that not work - play with the activation in the `beans.xml` in both JARs. Try to query the [BeanManager](http://docs.jboss.org/weld/reference/latest/en-US/html/extend.html#d0e4939) if the interceptor is registered.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I've found on Glassfish's JIRA, that this is a "feature", and will be  fixed only at v4 (v3.2 is skipped).

http://java.net/jira/browse/GLASSFISH-15119

Answer (score 2):

I had exactly the same problem with my [logging interceptor](https://github.com/t1/logging-interceptor/) on JBoss 7 and fixed it by *overlaying* the complete interceptor's jar into the application.

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <configuration>
                <overlays>
                    <overlay>
                        <groupId>com.github.t1</groupId>
                        <artifactId>logging-interceptor</artifactId>
                        <type>jar</type>
                        <targetPath>WEB-INF/classes</targetPath>
                    </overlay>
                </overlays>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.t1</groupId>
        <artifactId>logging-interceptor</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

You'll still have to activate the interceptor in the application's `breans.xml`.

Not nice, but it works. In Java EE 7, it works without the activation by annotating the interceptor as `@Priority`.

Comment: The `@Priority` annotation fixed my issue. Thanks :)